# Creating a Movie in Matlab Using Several Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, movie

I'm relatively new to Matlab and am trying to make a .avi file of several curves (Legendre polynomials) being traced out with a red dot tracing out each curve.  I've done this before with a single set of parametric equations and linspace, and it seemed to work fine.  I would think that the code would essentially be the same for what I'm wanting to do here, but I keep getting the following error message each time I try to run the program:

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> legpolymov at 25
    plot(x(1:2*i),y0(1:2*i));
```

My code is listed below.  Is there something I'm doing wrong or just missing, or is there maybe a better/more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

```
clc
clear all;
close all;
delete legpolymov.txt
diary legpolymov.txt
figure
hold all
t=linspace(-2,2,500);
x = t;
y0 = 1;
y1 = t;
y2 = (3/2)*t.^2 - (1/2);
y3 = (5/2)*t.^3 - ((3/2)*t);
y4 = (3/8) - ((15/4)*t.^2) + ((35/8)*t.^4);
y5 = ((15/8)*t) - ((35/4)*t.^3) + ((63/8)*t.^5);
plot(x,y0)
plot(x,y1)
plot(x,y2)
plot(x,y3)
plot(x,y4)
plot(x,y5)
axis equal
M=moviein(50);
for i=1:50
    plot(x(1:2*i),y0(1:2*i));
    plot(x(1:2*i),y1(1:2*i));
    plot(x(1:2*i),y2(1:2*i));
    plot(x(1:2*i),y3(1:2*i));
    plot(x(1:2*i),y4(1:2*i));
    plot(x(1:2*i),y5(1:2*i));
    hold all
    plot(x(2*i),y0(2*i),'k*');
    plot(x(2*i),y1(2*i),'k*');
    plot(x(2*i),y2(2*i),'k*');
    plot(x(2*i),y3(2*i),'k*');
    plot(x(2*i),y4(2*i),'k*');
    plot(x(2*i),y5(2*i),'k*');
    axis([-2 2 -1 1])
    a = texlabel('alpha');
    title('Legendre Polynomials for (1-x^2)y''''-2xy''+ \alpha  * (\alpha +1) = 0');
    xlabel('x-axis')
    ylabel('y-axis')
    M(i)=getframe;
    hold off
end

movie(M)

movie2avi(M,'Legendre1','FPS',7)
diary off
```

Comment: Besides the perfectly good answer to your question below; making a new plot in each loop is slow. You can for example create a full set of needed points and move them with the 'get' (e.g. 'get(h,'XData')') and 'set' commands or you can create a single point and move it around, whilst not removing old values from the figure (see 'Erasemode'). Use 'drawnow' to update the figure in each loop.

Comment: @A.Klomp - That's a very good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because your `y0` variable is only a single value, yet the other values of `y1,...y5` are arrays.  As such, you're indexing `y0` in your loop in such a way that you're assuming it's an array when it's not.

To ensure that the sizes are consistent when you're running this code, you need to make sure that `y0` is a `1 x 500` array as well.  As such, you need to replace your `y0` statement with:

```
y0 = ones(1,500);
```

Your code should run after doing this replacement.

---

## Some minor notes

I just ran this code on my end, and it doesn't seem to be plotting properly using what you have above in its exact form, except for the `y0` correction I made.  In order to get this to run, I suggest you make the following changes:

- Place your `hold all;` statement at the **beginning** of the `for` loop.  This way all of the points, including your curves, get plotted.  Take it out from the middle of the `for` loop and put it at the beginning.
- You have 500 data points, and your `for` loop is plotting the data in multiples of 2.  As such, you should increase your `for` loop limits from `1:50` to `1:250`.  In other words:

  ```
  for i = 1 : 250
      %// Insert code here
  end
  ```

Once I made these changes, I got your code to work.

Comment: That was really dumb of me. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Alan - haha, you're welcome.  Happens to all of us.  Good luck!